# condition in a switch case codition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have a collection from the database. And in the collection there is a check witch status a vcheq has.

The collection is like this:

```
  List<EcheqSubmissionInfoApi> submissions = await _patientDbContext.EcheqSubmissions
                .Where(s => s.AssignedToId == participantId)
                .OrderBy(s => (int)s.Status)
                .ThenByDescending(s => s.AssignedOnUtc)
                .Select(i => ConvertToPartialApi(i)).ToListAsync();
```

and the ConvertToPartialApi method looks like this:

```
 private static EcheqSubmissionInfoApi ConvertToPartialApi(EcheqSubmission submission)
        {         

            return new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi
            {
                Id = submission.Id,
                Status = submission.Status.StatusDbToApi(),
                DefinitionId = submission.DefinitionId,
                SubmittedOnUtc = submission.SubmittedOnUtc,
                AssignedByOrgId = submission.AssignedByOrgId,
                AssignedByProfId = submission.AssignedByProfId,
                AssignedOnUtc = submission.AssignedOnUtc,
                AssignedToId = submission.AssignedToId,
                ValidUntilUtc = submission.ValidUntilUtc,
                CurrentPage = submission.CurrentPage,
                Progress = submission.Progress
            };
        }
```

and the StatusDbToApi is the switch case, like this:

```
public static EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(this EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus)
        {
            EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;
            EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi;

            if (echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
            else
            {

                switch (dbStatus)
                {
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                        break;

                    //case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Expired:
                    //    status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
                    //    break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
                }
            }
            return status;
        }
```

But now I want to build a check for the expired status. like this:

```
 if (echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
```

But of course you will get an error on that line, because it is unassigned.

But how to do it correct?

Thank you

Or how to refactor this?

if I do it like this:

```
 EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi();

            if (echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
```

```
ValidUntilUtc
```

is always null

oke, I put this:

```
public class EcheqSubmission{
   public EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus, EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi)
        {
            EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;
           // EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi();

            if (echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
            else
            {

                switch (dbStatus)
                {
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                        break;

                    //case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Expired:
                    //    status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
                    //    break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
                }
            }
            return status;
        }
```

}

in the class:

```
EcheqSubmission
```

what is then the return type of this:

```
 private static EcheqSubmissionInfoApi ConvertToPartialApi(EcheqSubmission submission)
        {         

          var result =  new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi
            {
                Id = submission.Id,
                Status = submission.Status.StatusDbToApi(),
                DefinitionId = submission.DefinitionId,
                SubmittedOnUtc = submission.SubmittedOnUtc,
                AssignedByOrgId = submission.AssignedByOrgId,
                AssignedByProfId = submission.AssignedByProfId,
                AssignedOnUtc = submission.AssignedOnUtc,
                AssignedToId = submission.AssignedToId,
                ValidUntilUtc = submission.ValidUntilUtc,
                CurrentPage = submission.CurrentPage,
                Progress = submission.Progress
            };

            result.Status = submission.Status.StatusDbToApi();


        }
```

Comment: Use : EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status = new EcheqSubmissionStatusApi() ;

Comment: StatusDbToApi should not be a static method but a method part of the EcheqSubmission class. Status = submission.GetStatusBasedOnValidity()

Comment: Oke, but anyway it feels this is not good looking code. isnt?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, as will always return the same value. You either has to take the value as a parameter of the method, be a static member of the _class_  or have a value dynamic assign in the method itself.

Comment: It seems you actually want to pass `submission.ValidUntilUtc` to the `StatusDbToApi` method to use that.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to fix your issue;

1) Feed `submission.ValidUntilUtc` as a parameter into `StatusDbToApi()` so you have a simple `DateTime` to check against

2) First create your `EcheqSubmissionInfoApi` without filling its status, and then set its status after the creation:

```
var result = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi
            {
                Id = submission.Id,
                DefinitionId = submission.DefinitionId,
                SubmittedOnUtc = submission.SubmittedOnUtc,
                AssignedByOrgId = submission.AssignedByOrgId,
                AssignedByProfId = submission.AssignedByProfId,
                AssignedOnUtc = submission.AssignedOnUtc,
                AssignedToId = submission.AssignedToId,
                ValidUntilUtc = submission.ValidUntilUtc,
                CurrentPage = submission.CurrentPage,
                Progress = submission.Progress
            };
result.Status = submission.Status.StatusDbToApi();
```

3) Rewrite `StatusDbToApi` into a non-static method on `EcheqSubmissionStatus` that returns the correct status.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you. But where is the return type?

Comment: and this method: public static EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(this EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus ) has five references

Comment: Hi Mark. Are you there?

Comment: It's not a chat app, I need to sleep too :) The return type for option 3 would be `EcheqSubmissionStatusApi`. Seems like the method you edited in should work, doesn't it?

Comment: ? But yes, but I put an extra parameter in the method. So and it has a reference on it in this method:

Comment: But you example is not correct. Because this:  result.Status = submission.Status.StatusDbToApi(); the method StatusDbToApi is now in the class: EcheqSubmission

Comment: And you mean to write the switch case in the class: EcheqSubmission. Not in the  EcheqSubmissionStatus